# Word for a satisfying tactile feeling?

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the word for a tactile satisfying feeling? Some examples include the feeling of magnets gently clicking together, the sound of a car door closing, or the feeling of pressing/clicking a really nice button.

Comment: The feeling of pressing/clicking a really nice button is tactile. But the magnets and car door examples aren't. They are pleasant sounds. Could you be misusing the word tactile? Please clarify.

Answer (score 2):

[crisp](http://www.ldoceonline.com/Textures,+Sounds-topic/crisp_2)

> *adjective*
>
> a picture or sound that is **crisp** is clear [= sharp]:

[solid](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/solid)

> *adjective*
>
> Strongly built or made of strong materials; not flimsy or slender: a
> solid door with good, secure locks

[firm](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/firm)

> *adjective*
>
> Having a solid, almost unyielding surface or structure:
> *the bed should be reasonably **firm**, but not too hard*

[**Ergonomics in the Automotive Design Process** by *Vivek D. Bhise*](https://books.google.com/books?id=GajMBQAAQBAJ&lpg=PR2&pg=PA71#v=onepage&q&f=false)

> #### Information Acquired Through Other Sensory Modalities
>
> Human factors engineers work with other engineers in specialized
> functions such as acoustics and sound engineering; noise, vibrations,
> and harshness; and interior trim and materials to make sure that the
> vehicle provides the necessary cues of the right type and magnitude
> and enhances the pleasing perceptions (e.g., sound of the exhaust that
> conveys engine power, sound of door closing that provides the feeling
> of "**solidness**" or "**solid build quality**," tactile feedback received
> from "**crisp**" detent feel while operating electrical switches, smell of
> "genuine" leather from the seats).

Answer (score 1):

> Delicious

The door slammed shut with a *delicious* thunk.

Answer (score 1):

**Pleasant** is a versatile word that also covers tactile pleasure.

Tactile has nothing to do with sounds, you get tactile pleasure when you touch something, and such a pleasure is available even for deaf people.

**Tactile** ([Collins Dictionary](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/tactile?showCookiePolicy=true))

> 1. of, relating to, affecting, or having a sense of touch  a tactile organ, tactile stimuli
> 2. (rare) capable of being touched; tangible

Where sounds are concerned, here is a list, **'Pleasant, soft and gentle sounds'** on [Macmillan Dictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/thesaurus-category/british/pleasant-soft-and-gentle-sounds).

'Pleasant to the Touch' article on [The Scientist](http://www.the-scientist.com/?articles.view/articleNo/32487/title/Pleasant-to-the-Touch/), which deals with touch-sensitive nerve fibers, may help.

> Light pressure that excites C-tactile fibers produces a gentle,
>   consistently pleasurable feeling.

Answer (score 1):

frisson:  a pleasurably intense stimulation of the feelings  [merim-webster] (http://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/frisson)
Might be a little intense for what you mean, but I like it.

Answer (score 0):

What the OP seeks to describe strikes me as **the pleasurable and peculiar sensation or experience of “excellence” and “precision.”** The experience is synesthetic, in general, and not merely or strictly tactile but also visual, aural, olfactory, and in some cases even gustatory.

> **excellence** *noun*: the quality of being outstanding or extremely good. "the award for *excellence* in engineering"
>
> *synonyms*: distinction, quality, superiority, brilliance 
>   see Google [**excellence**](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=navclient&aq=&oq=excellence+definition&ie=UTF-8&rlz=1T4VRHB_enUS620US620&q=excellence+definition&gs_l=hp..0.0j0i7i30l4.0.0.3.54443...........0.T7BZ_kDoeXI&gws_rd=ssl)
>
> **precision** *noun*: the quality, condition, or fact of being exact and accurate. "the deal was planned and executed with military *precision*"
>
> *synonyms*: exactness, exactitude, accuracy, correctness, preciseness 
>   see Google [**precision**](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=navclient&aq=&oq=excellence+definition&ie=UTF-8&rlz=1T4VRHB_enUS620US620&q=excellence+definition&gs_l=hp..0.0j0i7i30l4.0.0.3.54443...........0.T7BZ_kDoeXI&gws_rd=ssl)

Answer (score 0):

Like one of the commenters, I don’t see the tactile connection with closing car doors (unless you’re talking about that little butt-bump that’s required when it doesn’t close all the way…that’s not entirely disagreeable), but I do see it with the magnets, that little pull just before they connect and click.

Anyway, one of my favorites is sliding my hand/arm under the backside of my pillow to discover/experience its coolness, which I find [calming](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/calming), [comforting](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/comforting?showCookiePolicy=true), [soothing](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/soothing?showCookiePolicy=true), and [relaxing](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/relaxing?showCookiePolicy=true); any of which might also describe the feeling you get when clicking your magnets or rubbing your buttons.